# Simple svg css progress circle

Tags: html, css, svg

I am trying to look for a way to achieve a simple progress circle (static) with no animations. The examples I have found have very different offsets for percentage such as given in the example below. How do I make my progress circle in such a way that if I provide offset as 50%, then it is exactly 50% (half filled)?

```css
.u-absoluteCenter {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  margin: auto;
}
.u-flexCenter {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
.u-offscreen {
  position: absolute;
  left: -999em;
}
.demo {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  margin: auto;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
.progress {
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
}
.progress__value {
  stroke-dasharray: 0;
  stroke-dashoffset: 0;
}
@-webkit-keyframes progress {
  from {
    stroke-dashoffset: 339.292;
  }
  to {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
}
@keyframes progress {
  from {
    stroke-dashoffset: 339.292;
  }
  to {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<svg width="120" height="120" viewBox="0 0 120 120">
    <circle cx="60" cy="60" r="54" fill="none" stroke="#e6e6e6" stroke-width="12" />
    <circle cx="60" cy="60" r="54" fill="none" stroke="#f77a52" stroke-width="12"
        stroke-dasharray="339.292" stroke-dashoffset="339.292" />
</svg>
```

Comment: For 25% try `stroke-dasharray="84.823 254.469"` where the stroke 84.823 represents 25% of the path's length (339.292) and the gap (254.469) represents the 75%.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can leverage an SVG attribute to set the path length rather than having to calculate it.

[**`pathLength`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/pathLength) sets the length to whatever you need...say 100 for a progress bar.

> The pathLength attribute lets authors specify a total length for the path, in user units. This value is then used to calibrate the browser's distance calculations with those of the author, by scaling all distance computations using the ratio pathLength/(computed value of path length).

```
pathLength="100"
```

Then you can set the `stroke-dasharray` to 100 as well and then adjust the `stroke-dashoffset` as needed....

```css
::root {
  --val: 0;
}

svg {
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
}

.percent {
  stroke-dasharray: 100;
  stroke-dashoffset: calc(100 - var(--val));
}

.fifty {
  --val: 50;
}

.sixty {
  --val: 60;
}

.ninety {
  --val: 90;
}
```

```html
<svg width="120" height="120" viewBox="0 0 120 120">
    <circle cx="60" cy="60" r="54" fill="none" stroke="#e6e6e6" stroke-width="12" />
    <circle class="percent fifty" cx="60" cy="60" r="54" fill="none" stroke="#f77a52" stroke-width="12" pathLength="100" />
</svg>

<svg width="120" height="120" viewBox="0 0 120 120">
    <circle cx="60" cy="60" r="54" fill="none" stroke="#e6e6e6" stroke-width="12" />
    <circle class="percent sixty" cx="60" cy="60" r="54" fill="none" stroke="#f77a52" stroke-width="12" pathLength="100" />
</svg>


<svg width="120" height="120" viewBox="0 0 120 120">
    <circle cx="60" cy="60" r="54" fill="none" stroke="#e6e6e6" stroke-width="12" />
    <circle class="percent ninety" cx="60" cy="60" r="54" fill="none" stroke="#f77a52" stroke-width="12" pathLength="100" />
</svg>
```

Comment: But this only gives 3 values (50, 60, 90) and I think OP would need any value between 0 - 100. Does this apply?

Comment: The values are just for demonstration purposes. Adjusting the value is simple enough

Comment: Ah okay. Could you explain how can one provide a value from the HTML code? like 26%

Comment: Like this @Saif https://codepen.io/andywebo/pen/gORyOYQ ...just do the calc in the style attribute inline.

Comment: Just noticed that the calc(100 - x) value doesn't work within stroke-dashoffset on mobile Safari nor mobile Chrome (on iOS). Have to use the resultant number instead.

Answer (score 5):

As Paulie says, `pathLength` is the key to progress circles

A modern JavaScript Web Component (JSWC supported in all modern browsers) makes for a re-usable HTML Element

```html
 <svg-progress-circle percent="30"></svg-progress-circle>
 <svg-progress-circle percent="20" color="blue"></svg-progress-circle>
 <svg-progress-circle percent="80" color="gold"></svg-progress-circle>
```

[image]

Added a range-input for interactive demo purposes.

Percent is a property on the element, you can set with code like:

```js
    document.getElementById("Slider1").percent = <PERCENTAGE>;
```

If you don't want a dashed grey fullcircle, delete the dash setting from the `pathLenght=120` `path`

I used a `path` instead of overlapping `circles` because with some other settings the almost same code can create pie-charts.

```html
<style>
  svg { width: 150px; background: teal }
  svg-progress-circle[percent="100"] path { stroke: green }
</style>

<svg-progress-circle percent="30"></svg-progress-circle>
<svg-progress-circle percent="20" color="blue"></svg-progress-circle>
<svg-progress-circle percent="80" color="gold"></svg-progress-circle>

<script>
  customElements.define("svg-progress-circle", class extends HTMLElement {
    connectedCallback() {
      let d = 'M5,30a25,25,0,1,1,50,0a25,25,0,1,1,-50,0'; // circle
      this.innerHTML = 
      `<input type="range" min="0" max="100" step="10" value="30"`+ // delete 2 lines
      ` oninput="this.parentNode.percent=this.value" /><br>`+ // just for demo
      
      `<svg viewBox="0 0 60 60">
       <path stroke-dasharray="10 2"   stroke-dashoffset="-19" 
             pathlength="120" d="${d}" fill="grey" stroke="lightgrey" stroke-width="5"/>
       <path stroke-dasharray="30 70" stroke-dashoffset="-25" 
             pathlength="100" d="${d}" fill="none" 
             stroke="${this.getAttribute("color")||"red"}" stroke-width="5"/>
       <text x="50%" y="57%" text-anchor="middle">30%</text></svg>`;
       
      this.style.display='inline-block';
      this.percent = this.getAttribute("percent");
    }
    set percent(val = 0) {
      this.setAttribute("percent", val);
      let dash = val + " " + (100 - val);
      this.querySelector("path+path").setAttribute('stroke-dasharray', dash);
      this.querySelector("text").innerHTML = val + "%";
      this.querySelector("input").value = val;
    }
  })
</script>
```

Note: I am working on a complete Web Component that does Pie Graphs and fancy Progress circles like:

[image]

**But**, it is one of many side-projects... HTML examples and obfuscated source code available at https://pie-meister.github.io/