# I need to make like this gif animation in css, I stated with code but I cant reversed the animation

Tags: javascript, css, svg

I'm trying to simulate this animation for the progress bar with CSS or SVG
any way to do this animation?

I added my string as embedded code, I tried by SVG not CSS, this image takes from the video sent by the designer

The current code example I worked on it to try apply the animation

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas"),
    context = canvas.getContext("2d"),
    centerX = canvas.width / 2,
    centerY = canvas.height / 2,
    rad = (Math.PI * 2) / 50,
    speed = 1;
function blueCircle(speed) {
    context.save();
    context.beginPath();
    context.strokeStyle = "#ffffff";
    context.lineWidth = 4;
    context.arc(
        centerX,
        centerY,
        40,
        -Math.PI / 2,
        -Math.PI / 2 + speed * rad,
        false
    );
    context.stroke();
    context.restore();
}
function reblueCircle(speed) {
    context.save();
    context.beginPath();
    context.strokeStyle = "#ffffff69";
    context.lineWidth = 4;
    context.arc(
        centerX,
        centerY,
        40,
        -Math.PI / 2,
        -Math.PI / 2 + speed * rad,
        false
    );
    context.stroke();
    context.restore();
}
function whiteCircle() {
    context.save();
    context.beginPath();
    context.strokeStyle = "#ffffff69";
    context.lineWidth = 4;
    context.arc(centerX, centerY, 40, 0, Math.PI * 2, false);
    context.stroke();
    context.closePath();
    context.restore();
}
var res = false;
(function drawFrame() {
    window.requestAnimationFrame(drawFrame, canvas);
    context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    whiteCircle();
    blueCircle(speed);
    if (res) {
        speed -= 0.1;
        reblueCircle(speed);
    }
    if (speed > 50 && !res) {
        res = true;
    } else if (speed < 50 && !res) {
        speed += 0.1;
    } else if (speed > 50 && !res) {
        res = true;
    }
})();
```

```css
body {
    background: #000;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="84" height="84"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT: I solved your actual request, and without JS, CSS only:**

```css
::root {
  --val: 0;
}

svg {
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
}

.percent {
  animation: load 3s infinite;
  stroke-dasharray: 100;
}


@keyframes load {
  0% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
  20% {
    stroke-dashoffset: -100;
  }
  100% {
    stroke-dashoffset: -200;
  }
}
```

```html
<svg width="120" height="120" viewBox="0 0 120 120">
    <circle cx="60" cy="60" r="54" fill="none" stroke="#e6e6e6" stroke-width="12" />
    <circle class="percent" cx="60" cy="60" r="54" fill="none" stroke="#f77a52" stroke-width="12" pathLength="100" />
</svg>
```

---

**Old answer:**

A solution can be adapted from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66990496/simple-svg-css-progress-circle), like so:

```js
let increasing = true
let progress = 0

function updateProgress() {
  progress = increasing ? progress + 1 : progress - 1
  if(progress > 100) {
    progress = 100
    increasing = false
  }
  if(progress < 0) {
    progress = 0
    increasing = true
  }
  
  document.querySelector('svg circle.percent').style.setProperty('--value', progress);
  setTimeout(updateProgress, 50)
}

updateProgress()
```

```css
::root {
  --val: 0;
}

svg {
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
}

.percent {
  stroke-dasharray: 100;
  stroke-dashoffset: calc(100 - var(--value, 0));
  transition: all 0.1s;
}
```

```html
<svg width="120" height="120" viewBox="0 0 120 120">
    <circle cx="60" cy="60" r="54" fill="none" stroke="#e6e6e6" stroke-width="12" />
    <circle class="percent" cx="60" cy="60" r="54" fill="none" stroke="#f77a52" stroke-width="12" pathLength="100" />
</svg>
```

But I must say that if you implemented the canvas-solution by yourself, well done - why not just use that?

Comment: We need the animation like the gif exactly, you can please check the above image.

Comment: @ZeyadHabbab SO is not a free code-writing service

Comment: It certainly isn't, @Andreas! I updated the answer though, as I actually wondered myself how to solve it. Good luck @OP

Comment: I can understand what Sebastian said, actually I saw the same question posted by 
Zeyad Habbab yesterday, the question description is less than what I saw now, but when I was about to submit the answer, I found that he deleted the question

Comment: I'm actually quite happy to see the same problem today, although it means that the problem has not been solved, but at least the time spent yesterday was not wasted, but after reading a more detailed description of the problem, I realize that my answer may not be him Wanted, of course if I spent a little extra time modifying my code I could answer it, but someone already answered the question, so I gave up on doing it